# windows 10 Audio Bug - Red x on speaker icon

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, icons, speakers

I'm having a red x on speaker icon. I know few manual way to fix this but this is not permanent solutions. I have to try these steps every time I reboot the PC.

This is a bug that has been reported many times but no permanent solution.

[image]

Temporary solutions (Issue persists after reboot):

1. Restart Windows Audio Service and Windows Audio Endpoint service and it'll fix the "red x" icon.
2. Search for "Troubleshoot other problems" in Windows settings and run "Playing Audio" troubleshooter and it'll fix the "red x" icon.

Is there a permanent solution to this? After reboot the red x appears back, and I have to try the above solutions.

Comment: When the X is back, check Device Manager—are any (audio) devices reported as malfunctioning? Also check whether the Windows Audio service has crashed. Maybe also check Event Viewer, it could have relevant information in the System log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a permanent solution from this [article](https://www.repairwin.com/fix-lost-sound-after-windows-10-update/) Method 4:

1. Find the following registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations and if "ConsoleSecurity" value is "zero-length binary value" then proceed to step 2.

[image]

2. Launch command prompt as administrator and run the following command that replace the "ConsoleSecurity" value.

   REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations" /f /v ConsoleSecurity /t REG_BINARY /d 010014809c000000a800000000000000140000000200880006000000000014000100000001010000000000050400000000001400bf030f000101000000000005120000000000140089000f00010100000000000513000000000014008100000001010000000000051400000000001800bf030f000102000000000005200000002002000000001800210100000102000000000005200000002b020000010100000000000512000000010100000000000512000000
3. Reboot the system

Check the "Method 4. FIX Lost Sound issue by Modifying Registry" in this [article](https://www.repairwin.com/fix-lost-sound-after-windows-10-update/) for more information.